# What can be said about the dynamics of a flow just from knowing its Schwartzman asymptotic cycles?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, dynamical-systems

Consider a smooth flow $\{\phi_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ on a closed smooth manifold $M^n$. One approach to studying the dynamics of $\phi$ using algebraic topology is by studying its Schwartzman asymptotic cycles, introduced by Schwartzman in 1957 (see http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Asymptotic_cycles and references there). The basic idea is the following: Suppose $\phi$ is generated by a vector field $X$. Given a Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $M$ which is invariant under $\phi$, Schwartzman associates to it an "asymptotic cycle" $\mathcal{S}(\mu)\in H_1(M;\mathbb{R})$. Viewing $H_1(M;\mathbb{R})= H^1(M;\mathbb{R})^*$ the asymptotic cycle is a homomorphism $\mathcal{S}(\mu):H^1(M;\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$ \mathcal{S}(\mu)([\alpha])=\int \iota_X \alpha \ d\mu $$

for any closed $1$-form $\alpha$ on $M$. Let us denote by $\mathcal{S}(\phi)\subset H_1(M;\mathbb{R})$ the subset consisting of all elements of the form $\mathcal{S}(\mu)$, where $\mu$ is an invariant measure for $\phi$. It is easy to see that $\mathcal{S}(\phi)$ is convex. My question is: What can one say about the dynamics of $\phi$ from knowing $\mathcal{S}(\phi)$? I suppose there should be quite a bit to say, at least in extreme cases where for example $\mathcal{S}(\phi)$ is a point or $\mathcal{S}(\phi)=H_1(M;\mathbb{R})$. I would be extremely grateful for any ideas/comments, even with adapted assumptions or in a changed setting, or even if someone could suggest a great reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of Schwartzmann's theorems on this topic (reproved, later and in a somewhat different context, by David Fried) is that if $S(\phi)$ does not contain the origin, and if the closure of $S(\phi)$ minus the origin is contained in some open half space of $H_1(M;\mathbb{R})$, then the manifold $M$ fibers over the circle, meaning that there exists a smooth function $f : M \to S^1$ with no critical points. An equivalent statement is that the flow has a cross section, meaning an embedded, codimension 1, closed submanifold $F \subset M$ such that for each $x \in M$, the orbit through $x$ hits $F$ in forward time and in backward time.

Notice, this is not either of the extreme cases that you mention. Those cases are, I believe, harder to draw any conclusions from.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LeeMosher. This seems to be the kind of stuff I have been looking for, so i will definitely take a closer look. Do you by any chance have references for the results you mention above?

Comment: Schwartzmann's paper is "Asymptotic cycles", Ann. of Math. (2) 66 (1957). Fried's paper is "The geometry of cross sections to flows", Topology 21 (1982), no. 4, 353–371. I was quite wrong in saying "around the same time" in my original version of this answer!

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!